# Ubuntu 20.04 installation in expert mode

Tags: system-installation

How to install ubuntu in expert mode like in debian?
After selecting expert mode in F6 menu, nothing changes in installation process.

Comment: What configuration options are missing from the current installer to make you want an “expert mode”? 

Comment: @matigo, For example, I don't want to create a user other than root